# How to use remote desktop on Ubuntu without a X logged in session?

Tags: remote-desktop, ubuntu

I am able to use remote desktop on my Ubuntu server (with gnome desktop installed) when I also have an active session on the desktop. I would like to be able to remote desktop to this server after I just turn on the power (no screen and keyboard to the server), is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help?
http://imthi.com/blog/linux/ubuntu-904-remote-desktop-using-vncserver-without-monitor.php